# Проблемы с бесконечной прокруткой

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть страница, к которой прикручен [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll). Плагин нужен для бесконечной прокрутки. Скрипт берёт из страницы `view.php?page=[num]`. На view.php у меня код для постраничного вывода из БД.

Допустим, на view.php можно просмотреть 3 страницы (1 < page < 4). Т.е. страницы с номером больше количества страниц ничего не отображают. Но JS скрипт всё равно запрашивает станицы, которых нет, т.е. и до pagу = 250 он тоже дойдёт. Как это остановить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Infinite scroll is configured to die when it hits a 404 Not Found status code

Попробуйте отдать ему 404 ошибку, когда он просит несуществующую страницу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!

Comment: Это прекрасно, потому что я с этой штукой не знаком :)